# Move a line of text to a (new or existing) file, where the target (sub)directory is determined from the source file

Tags: logs, nginx

I have a custom Nginx access log where each line begins with a ISO8601 timestamp (`$time_iso8601` in Nginx parlance) and an epoch timestamp to millisecond decimal points (`$msec` in Nginx). Like this:

```
2023-01-16T20:19:57+00:00 1673900397.009 ips="…" rm="…" […]
2023-01-16T20:19:57+00:00 1673900397.140 ips="…" rm="…" […]
2023-01-16T20:19:57+00:00 1673900397.163 ips="…" rm="…" […]
2023-01-16T20:19:57+00:00 1673900397.205 ips="…" rm="…" […]
2023-01-16T20:19:57+00:00 1673900397.210 ips="…" rm="…" […]
```

For each line of the file, starting at the beginning, I would like to move the line to a (new or existing) file, where the target destination is built around the year, month and date of the ISO8601 timestamp in `/yyyy/mm/dd/access.log` format. For example, in the above snippet, I would like each line to be moved from the source `access.log` to the target `/2023/01/16/access.log`.

The target directory should be created if it does not exist. The target file should be created if it does not exist.

What tool(s) would you use for extracting the `yyyy`, `mm` and `dd` values?

Comment: [Log rotation directly within Nginx configuration file](https://www.cambus.net/log-rotation-directly-within-nginx-configuration-file/)

Answer (score 1):

Better use `logrotate` or `nginx` configuration, as [αғsнιη
said in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734089/move-a-line-of-text-to-a-new-or-existing-file-where-the-target-subdirectory/734092?noredirect=1#comment1393405_734089)

If you want to implement this with `awk` for fun:

```
awk -F'[-T]' '{
    dir=$1"/"$2"/"$3
    rc=system("mkdir -p " dir)
    if (rc != 0) exit
    print $0 >> dir"/access.log"
    close(dir"/access.log")
}' access.log
# rm -f access.log
```

The `FS` `F`ield `S`eparator `-F` is set to both dashes `-` and `T` in a character class.

##### Output dir(s)/file(s)

```
$ find
./2023
./2023/01
./2023/01/16
./2023/01/16/access.log
```

Comment: also it's not efficient to call external command `system("external-cmd")` for every single line awk reads as it's more likely the 99.99% (if log rotation applied) of the logs will be for the same calendar day or otherwise it's good to buffer the days and if not seen previously so once call the external commnad to create the path